# How to migrate oracle's pipelined function into PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

As I am newbie to plpgSQL,

I stuck while migrating a Oracle query into PostgreSQL.

Oracle query:

```
create or replace FUNCTION employee_all_case(
   p_ugr_id IN integer,
   p_case_type_id IN integer
)
RETURN number_tab_t PIPELINED
--       LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
--     COST 100
--     VOLATILE 
--     AS $$
--     DECLARE
is
  l_user_id        NUMBER;
  l_account_id     NUMBER;
BEGIN
  l_user_id      := p_ugr_id;
  l_account_id   := p_case_type_id;
  FOR cases IN
    (SELECT ccase.case_id, ccase.employee_id
     FROM ct_case ccase
       INNER JOIN ct_case_type ctype
         ON (ccase.case_type_id=ctype.case_type_id)
     WHERE ccase.employee_id = l_user_id)
  LOOP
    IF cases.employee_id IS NOT NULL THEN
      PIPE ROW (cases.case_id);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;
--$$
```

When I execute this function then I get the following result

```
select * from table(select employee_all_case(14533,1190) from dual)
```

[image]

My question here is: I really do not understand the pipelined function and how can I obtain the same result in PostgreSQL as Oracle query ?

Please help.

Comment: Not an answer but In Oracle `select * from table(select employee_all_case(14533,1190) from dual)` is not required. `select * from table(employee_all_case(14533,1190))` is enough

Answer (score 2):

Thank you guys, your solution was very helpful.

I found the desire result:

```
-- select * from employee_all_case(14533,1190);

-- drop function employee_all_case

  create or replace FUNCTION employee_all_case(p_ugr_id IN integer ,p_case_type_id IN integer)
returns table (case_id double precision)
  -- PIPELINED
   LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100
 VOLATILE 
 AS $$
 DECLARE
 -- is
  l_user_id        integer;
  l_account_id     integer;
BEGIN
  l_user_id      := cp_lookup$get_user_id_from_ugr_id(p_ugr_id);
  l_account_id   := cp_lookup$acctid_from_ugr(p_ugr_id);
  RETURN QUERY SELECT ccase.case_id
    FROM ct_case ccase
    INNER JOIN ct_case_type ctype ON ccase.case_type_id = ctype.case_type_id
    WHERE ccase.employee_id = p_ugr_id
    and ccase.employee_id IS NOT NULL; 
    --return NEXT;
END;
$$
```

[image]

Comment: There is no need for PL/pgSQL here and the two local variables seem to be useless as you don't use them at all and thus the two functions calls are also unnecessary

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name

Yeah I fogot to change the language and as far as two variables are concerned, this query is bigger. It's used somewhere else.

Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You would rewrite that to a *set returning function*:

- Change the return type to

  ```
  RETURNS SETOF integer
  ```

  and do away with the `PIPELINED`.
- Change the `PIPE ROW` statement to

  ```
  RETURN NEXT cases.case_id;
  ```

Of course, you will have to do the obvious syntactic changes, like using `integer` instead of `NUMBER` and putting the `IN` before the parameter name.

But actually, it is quite unnecessary to write a function for that. Doing it in a single `SELECT` statement would be both simpler and faster.

Answer (score 1):

Pipelined functions are best translated to a simple SQL function returning a table.

Something like this:

```
create or replace function employee_all_case(p_ugr_id integer, p_case_type_IN integer)
   returns table (case_id integer)
as
$$
  SELECT ccase.case_id
  FROM ct_case ccase
     INNER JOIN ct_case_type ctype ON ccase.case_type_id = ctype.case_type_id
  WHERE ccase.employee_id = p_ugr_id
    and cases.employee_id IS NOT NULL;
$$
language sql;
```

Note that your sample code did not use the second parameter `p_case_type_id`.

Usage is also more straightforward:

```
select * 
from employee_all_case(14533,1190);
```

Answer (score 1):

Before diving into the solution, I will provide some information which will help you to understand better.
So basically PIPELINED came into picture for improving memory allocation at run time.

- As you all know collections will occupy space when ever they got created. So the more you use, the more memory will get allocated.
- Pipelining negates the need to build huge collections by piping rows out of the function.
- saving memory and allowing subsequent processing to start before all the rows are generated.
- Pipelined table functions include the PIPELINED clause and use the PIPE ROW call to push rows out of the function as soon as they are created, rather than building up a table collection.

> By using Pipelined how memory usage will be optimized?

Well, it's very simple. instead of storing data into an array, just process the data by using **pipe row(desired type)**. This actually returns the row and process the next row.

> coming to solution in plpgsql

1. simple but not preferred while storing large data.

- Remove PIPELINED from return declaration and return an array of desired type. something like `RETURNS typrec2[]`.
- Where ever you are using pipe row(), add that entry to array and finally return that array.

2. create a temp table like

> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table (required fields) ON COMMIT DROP;

and insert data into it. Replace **pipe row** with insert statement and finally return statement like

> return query select * from temp_table

- **The best link for understanding **PIPELINED in oracle** [https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions]
- pretty ordinary for postgres reference [http://manojadinesh.blogspot.com/2011/11/pipelined-in-oracle-as-well-in.html]

Hope this helps some one conceptually.